# Exponential of nth order derivative

Tags: analysis, operator-theory

When dealing with an exponential operator of the form $e^{\vec a \cdot \vec \nabla}f(\vec x)$, I understand how this simply shifts the argument of the function by $a⃗$ . My question is what happens when the exponent is a higher order derivative? Say you have a first order differential operator $D$, what would $e^{aD^{n}}f(x)$ look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's painfully little that you can say in general, other than that the PDE $\partial_t f(t,x) = D^n f(t,x)$ with initial condition $f(t_0,x) = g(x)$, given suitable domain and boundary conditions, is at least morally solved by $f(t,x) = e^{-(t-t_0)D^n}g(x)$. Indeed, you can understand $$f(t,x) = e^{-t \hat{n} \cdot \nabla}g(x) = g(x-t\hat{n})$$ as solving the PDE $\partial_t f(t,x) = (\hat{n} \cdot \nabla) f(t,x)$ with initial condition $f(0,x) = g(x)$.

As an example, $e^{-t \Delta}$ is the so-called *heat operator*, which arises since, given suitable domain of definition and boundary conditions, $f(t,x)$ satisfies the heat equation with initial condition $f(t_0,x) = g(x)$ if and only if $f(t,x) = e^{-(t-t_0) \Delta} g(x)$. Hence, the problem of computing the heat operator $e^{-t\Delta}$ is the same as the problem of solving the heat equation for your given domain and boundary conditions, for arbitrary initial condition.